# angularjs dynamically set bind or model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm trying to dynamically populate columns in a table: http://jsfiddle.net/REjUv/1/

$scope has an array of column definitions each with a property name and an array of items for the rows

i'm trying to set the content of the td elements to the property of the item with the name in the relevant column

```
<div ng-app ng-controller='ListController'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat='column in columns'>{{column.text}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat='item in items'>
            <td ng-repeat='column in columns'>
                <!--how do i set the ng-bind to item.[column.name]-->
                <label type='text' ng-bind='item.name' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>


function ListController($scope){
    $scope.columns = [
        { name: 'id', text: 'Id' },
        { name: 'code', text: 'Code' },
        { name: 'name', text: 'Name' }
    ];

    $scope.items = [
        { id:1, code: 'A', name: 'AAA' },
        { id:2, code: 'B', name: 'BBB' },
        { id:3, code: 'C', name: 'CCC' },
        { id:4, code: 'D', name: 'DDD' }
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This?

```
<td ng-repeat='column in columns'>{{item[column.name]}</td>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/REjUv/2/)